# ASP.NET MVC 2: Html.ActionLink another function within the controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to figure out how controllers work. Obviously when a page first loads, the `ActionResult Index()` is called. But how do you call other function within the controller?

I tried using `Html.ActionLink("Click Me", "ControllerFunction")` but it just looked for a page called "ControllerFunction."

What I'd like to be able to do is call a function within the controller that updates the view data and then refreshes the page (or Ajax).

How is this supposed to work? Because right now the only useful function within the controller is `Index()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller:

```
public HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult AjaxAction()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

and then in the Index.aspx view you could have a link and an empty div which will harbor the result of the AJAX request:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("ajax test", "ajaxaction", null, 
    new { id = "ajaxtest" })%>
<div id="result"></div>
```

which you would then enhance with javascript (jquery in my case):

```
$(function() {
    $('#ajaxtest').click(function() {
        $('#result').load(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

When you click on the link an AJAX request will be sent to `/home/ajaxlink` which would render a partial view `AjaxAction.ascx` and insert its contents into the result div.

Comment: But what's the point of the controller function? All it's doing is returning the view again, and from my example, all that did was try and find a page similar to "ajaxaction" ...

Comment: The point is that this controller function (called action) will based on the user request manipulate the model, use a repository to fetch data from a database, perform many other things before returning a view unless of course you want this view to be totally static.

Answer (score 0):

you clearly are missing the basics of MVC :)

have a look at this great introduction to MVC: http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/matthijs/aspnet-mvc-2-basics-introduction-by-scott-hanselman

Comment: Totally new to this, yup! I'm being forced to learn like this because the need is desperate at work... but I'm willing enough! Any information you can grant me would be absolutely wonderful. Thanks!